# Load Assets from Content to Scene using C++ in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I loaded a .fbx object named "plane" into my content folder. I have an empty Actor on the scene with an Added C++ Scene Component. Using the C++ code, I'd like to access my .fbx object "Plane" and load it to the scene through CODE. Much like in unity ex:

Instantiate(Resources.Load(**FILEPATH**),new Vector3(x,y,z),new Quaternion());

Comment: Does Unreal automatically pick up the FBX file? (i.e. does it automatically show up in the content browser or do you have to import first). If it does, you can probably use the [`AssetRegistry`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Assets/Registry/index.html) module  If it isn't in the content browser, don't think UE has any knowledge of it until you import. Once imported, you can probably use the AssetRegistry. 

Why do you want to do it this way btw? (As opposed to assigning in the editor?)

Comment: Hi there, did you manage to find a solution for this? I am attempting a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just place a fbx file into your level, you have to use an actor for that. Add a static mesh component to your actor and on this component set the mesh to your fbx asset.

You can not directly load stuff from files in C++, you have to use the names from imported assets. The whole point of this is that you can move files and assets around without your code breaking.